# xla vs xlam addin, what is the difference?

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

Could someone please explain the difference between an xla Excel addin format and an xlam Excel addin format? Googling didnt provide anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The m stands for macro-enabled which is the new format (as from Excel 2007).
These are add-ins that may call macro's. 
On the other hand, you could also have xlax extensions, which are meant for macro-freeworkbooks.

Note also the difference between xls and xlsm, where xlsx files also don't contain macro's.

Why? My guess is that the main reason would be security.
Some people don't like to receive files, not knowing if there are potentially harmful macro's in it. In the old format, you could not make the distinction based on the file extension.

Comment: + 1 :) @mezamorphic: Both are Add-In Files. The main difference is that XLAM cannot be opened in earlier office versions (Pre 2007). And hence when you are creating Add-Ins which has to be compatible with earlier versions then always create an XLA instead of XLAM.

Comment: The main difference is what @SiddharthRout highlighted: old format vs new format and compatibility issues. An add-in without macros would not be particularly useful IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Both files are macro enabled files:

- XLA files are excel files for office 97 - that are loaded as addins
- XLAM files are excel 2003+ files, which are actually zip files that have xml documents inside them per opendocument protocol.